# Correcting CS0009 Error When Creating Integration Services Project

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, bids, visual-studio-2008

Tried to open an SSIS project I had been working on today and received this lovely error:

Unable to generate temporary class (result=1)
error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0_b77a5c561934e089\System.XML.dll' could not be opened -- 'No metadata was found.'

Anyone know why this happens and how to correct it, I've Googled and haven't found any valid solutions relating directly to SSIS. It is only happening with BIDS 2008 and SSIS project types and I tried the same packages (as well as creating a new one) on my other machine and it was fine.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot actually browse to that directory I used Command Prompt on another machine to copy the System.Xml.dll and then transfered it over to the problem directory with Command Prompt on the machine I was getting this error on.

That simple.